# Multiple call to onselect from select element with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: html, select, angularjs, onselect, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im using an HTML select element to display an entity's field that has enumerated values in it.

Within the page, I have multiple fields for the entity, therefore multiple select elements.

Im using an Angular ng-repeat to display each field, by creating a select within the ng-repeat on my table row. I want to capture the "onselect" event when an item is selected from any of the drop downs, the trouble is, whenever the user selects a value in one drop down, the event fires for all drop downs on the page.

My html:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng:controller="TodoCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="prop in customForm">
            <td>{{prop.legend}}</td>
            <td>
                <select ng-name="prop.name" ng-model="entity[prop.name]"
                        ng-options="val as val for val in prop.enumeratedValues"
                        onselect="{{fireSelectEvent(prop.name)}}"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Calls Made</td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="call in callLog">
            <td>{{call}}</td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
//'use strict';
function TodoCtrl($scope) {


    $scope.customForm =
    [
        {name:"aval", legend: "A Value", enumeratedValues: ["1","2","3"], editable: true},
        {name:"bval", legend: "B Value", enumeratedValues: ["4","5","6"], editable: true},
        {name:"cval", legend: "C Value", enumeratedValues: ["7","8","9"], editable: true}
    ];

    $scope.entity = {};
    $scope.callLog = [];

    $scope.fireSelectEvent = function( propName )
    {
        console.log("Prop=" + propName + " value=" + $scope.entity[propName]);


        $scope.callLog.push( propName );        
    }
}
```

My fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/utgwG/

Good luck. We're all counting on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `onselect` attribute?  You're seeing `fireSelectEvent` fire that many times, because you've bound the `onselect` attribute using [Angular interpolation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate).

What I'm guessing you want to do is: `ng-change="fireSelectEvent(prop.name)"`

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utgwG/2/